# Exclude non-Java JARs from Maven Javadoc plugin processing

Tags: maven, javadoc

I have a multi-module project which builds a couple of JARs and then distributed them into two WARs.

However, one of the JARs does not contain any Java code at all, merely (maven-filtered) resources. This leads to warnings during the build like these:

```
[…]
[INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:2.8:jar (attach-javadocs) @ foo-services ---
[INFO] The goal 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.8:javadoc' has not been previously called for the module: 'de.tarent.foo:foo-rsrcs:jar:1.3.900-SNAPSHOT'. Trying to invoke it...

[WARNING] Creating fake javadoc directory to prevent repeated invocations: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/FooTool/workspace/foo-backend/foo-rsrcs/target/apidocs
[ERROR] Error fetching link: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/FooTool/workspace/foo-backend/foo-rsrcs/target/apidocs/package-list. Ignored it.

[INFO] 
Loading source files for package de.tarent.foo.rest.transformation...
[…]
```

I found how I can exclude javadoc stuff by package, but not by artifact.

The plugin is currently included ONLY in the parent POM, like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

While it *is* run during “compilation” of the resources-only JAR, it (obviously) produces no result, thus the warning (as it’s not excluded either).

How can I either make it produce something or, probably preferably, exclude the `foo-rsrcs` module?

Comment: This is now https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAVADOC-523 (modulo the usual JIRA formatting bugs…).

Answer (score -1):

Giving such a resources dependency the scope `runtime` should be sufficient to fix this issue. It will actually have better effects for other plugins too.

Comment: The JARs are needed during compilation.